# Trigonometric derivative of integral with different results

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I have to compute the following operation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int_0^{b(r)}\frac{1}{1+C\exp({-1[\theta-c]})}d\theta.
\end{equation}
 According to the trigonometric functions, and as represented in the figure below, I can write:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int_0^{b(r)}\frac{1}{1+C\exp\left({-1\left[\arcsin{\left(\frac{h}{r}\right)}-c\right]}\right)}d\theta.$$

The derivative, by the second theorem of calculus and by chain rule, would then be equal to 
$$\frac{1}{1+C\exp\left({-1\left[\arcsin{\left(\frac{h}{b(r)}\right)}-c\right]}\right)}\cdot b'(r),$$
which imposes the constraint that |h/b(r)|<1.

---

At the same time, following the trigonometric rules, I can equivalently write the first equation as

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int_0^{b(r)}\frac{1}{1+C\exp\left({-1\left[\arccos{\left(\frac{b(r)}{r}\right)}-c\right]}\right)}d\theta,$$

and in this case the derivative would be equal to

$$\frac{1}{1+C\exp\left({-1\left[\arccos{\left(\frac{b(r)}{b(r)}\right)}-c\right]}\right)}\cdot b'(r) = \frac{1}{1+C\exp({c})}\cdot b'(r),$$
which now is a totally different expression and does not impose any constraint on the values of $b(r)$ and $r$.

Probably it's a very silly question, and I am not seeing a very obvious point here, put how can I possibly get two different solutions, starting from the same point?

[image]

Comment: You can use the fundamental theorem of calculus directly in the first integral. Why do you want to express $\theta$ as a function of $r$?

Comment: @bjorn93 because I am using stochastic geometry and all my following analysis will be based on parameter $r$ as the variable.

Comment: Yes, but I am still trying to understand why, when I replace $\theta$ with $r$, I obtain different solutions if I consider $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$. Shouldn't I get always the same expression?

Comment: I had a mistake in my previous comment. It's
$$F(r)=\int_0^{b(r)}f(\theta)\,d\theta \Rightarrow F'(r)=f(b(r))b'(r) $$
By replacing $\theta$ with a function of $r$, you no longer have an integrand in terms of $\theta$. So what expression are you actually integrating then? You can simply pull that expression out of the integral assuming that $r$ is fixed.

Comment: @bjorn93 I understand, and in fact this is equal to what I have in the first part of the question, i.e., $f(b(r))b'(r)$. However, what about the second solution that I am obtaining? Where does that come from?